# Next-App deployed on Vercel: Request for new refresh-token leads to unwanted 304 Not Modified-response

Tags: next.js, jwt, vercel, http-status-code-304

I built a Next-app on the frontend and deployed it on Vercel (and a Django-app on the backend deployed on Heroku). Authentication is implemented with JWTs and and a Next-API route connecting the Next-Frontend with the Django-Backend.

The authentication workflow relevant for my problem is the following:

Whenever an authenticated user visits a protected page, a request (with the current refresh-token) is sent to the backend, asking for a fresh pair of access & refresh tokens. This works perfectly fine when testing locally the production-optimized version of the Nextjs-app (via `next build` & `next start`): I receive a 200 OK response with the new refresh- and access-tokens.

However - when I do the same thing in my Vercel-deployed app, after the first request/response-cycle for new tokens (which works as expected), I always get back a `304 Not Modified`-response, which does not have any cookies in its Headers. I can see that my Django-server sends off the new tokens but somehow they get lost on the Next-server.

I did some research and if I understand correctly, Vercel has some caching rules, that lead to this behavior. However, I could not find any solution on how to avoid this from happening.

Does anyone know, what to do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, sharing the solution for anyone who might run into this problem in the future. When it comes to caching - Vercel's production servers behave differently than the test server you can run with `npm run start`. While the former caches certain responses by default for performance reasons, the latter does not do that.

To deactivate the caching for the response giving me the unwanted `304 Not Modified` status, i simply added a `Cache-Control`-header with `no-cache`, `no-store`, `max-age=0` and `must-revalidate` directives to it:

```
export default async function refresh(req, res) {
  ...
  if (apiRes.status === 200) {    
    // "Cache-Control"-header needed for production to avoid Vercel's default 
    // response caching mechanism        
    res.setHeader(
      "Cache-Control",
      "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    );
    ...
```

Comment: Still getting the cached data